# Why file operation assigned twice in ldd3 sample code?

Tags: linux, drivers

https://github.com/martinezjavier/ldd3/blob/master/scull/main.c#L601

```
static void scull_setup_cdev(struct scull_dev *dev, int index)
{
    int err, devno = MKDEV(scull_major, scull_minor + index);

    cdev_init(&dev->cdev, &scull_fops); 
    dev->cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
    dev->cdev.ops = &scull_fops;
```

we can see `scull_fops` was assigned twice by `cdev_init()` and `cdev.ops`, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scull_fops` isn’t *assigned* twice, it’s *used* twice. It’s *defined* [elsewhere in the same file](https://github.com/martinezjavier/ldd3/blob/master/scull/main.c#L551), then its address is passed to `cdev_init`, and assigned to `dev->cdev.ops`.

As you mention, this explicit assignment to `dev->cdev.ops` is unnecessary since `cdev_init` does it too. As [Johan Myréen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/187960/johan-myr%C3%A9en) [says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/465003/why-file-operation-assigned-twice-in-ldd3-sample-code/465006?noredirect=1#comment846567_465006), this is an inefficiency in the LDD3 example code — the example code is newer than the corresponding line in `cdev_init`, so it was already unnecessary when it was written. (It would be interesting to see if the same mistake is reproduced elsewhere, to see how much “real” driver code was written based on the LDD3 example!)

The function could be simplified to

```
static void scull_setup_cdev(struct scull_dev *dev, int index)
{
    int err, devno = MKDEV(scull_major, scull_minor + index);

    cdev_init(&dev->cdev, &scull_fops);
    dev->cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
    err = cdev_add (&dev->cdev, devno, 1);
    /* Fail gracefully if need be */
    if (err)
        printk(KERN_NOTICE "Error %d adding scull%d", err, index);
}
```

Comment: when using cdev_init, cdev() should already know its address, why need to assign to cdev.ops again ?

Comment: `dev->cdev.ops` is assigned twice, once in `cdev_init` and then again in `scull_setup_cdev`. This is obviously a bug in the LDD3 sample code.

Answer (score 0):

see this link to confirm it do twice:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6f0d349d922ba44e4348a17a78ea51b7135965b1/fs/char_dev.c#L656

```
void cdev_init(struct cdev *cdev, const struct file_operations *fops)
{
  memset(cdev, 0, sizeof *cdev);
  INIT_LIST_HEAD(&cdev->list);
  kobject_init(&cdev->kobj, &ktype_cdev_default);
  cdev->ops = fops;
}
```